# Data is not inserting in the database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-3.5

I am creating a wbsite and I have the following code in c#.net

```
public void btnSubmit_Click(TextBox txtEmailAdd, TextBox txtFirstName, TextBox txtLastName, TextBox txtDob, DropDownList drpdwnState, TextBox txtZipCode, DropDownList drpdwnCountry, Label lblMsg)
    {
        string[] ParameterName = { "@EmailId", "@FirstName", "@LastName", "@DOB", "@State", "@PostalCode", "@Country"};
        ArrayList ParameterValue = new ArrayList();
        ParameterValue.Add(Convert.ToString(txtEmailAdd.Text));
        ParameterValue.Add(Convert.ToString(txtFirstName.Text));
        ParameterValue.Add(Convert.ToString(txtLastName.Text));
        ParameterValue.Add(Convert.ToString(txtDob.Text));       
        ParameterValue.Add(Convert.ToString(drpdwnState.SelectedItem.Text));
        ParameterValue.Add(Convert.ToString(txtZipCode.Text));
        ParameterValue.Add(Convert.ToString(drpdwnCountry.SelectedItem.Text));

        int i = objDataAccess.Insert_Update_DeleteRecord("[WaterKingdom].[Master].[usp_EmailForm_Insert]", CommandType.StoredProcedure, ParameterName, ParameterValue);

            lblMsg.Text = "Thanks for sending mail.";

    }
```

and I am using the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Master].[usp_EmailForm_Insert]
@EmailId varchar(50),
@FirstName varchar(50),
@LastName varchar(50),
@DOB varchar(50),
@State varchar(50),
@PostalCode varchar(50),
@Country varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [Master].[EmailForm]
(EmailId,FirstName,LastName,DOB,State,PostalCode,Country)
VALUES
 (@EmailId,@FirstName,@LastName,@DOB,@State,@PostalCode,@Country)
END
```

still the data is not storing in the database.where is the fault Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sqlprofiler, observe traces, you will be able to see what query dbms receives. but please use try catch first.